# How to change nestjs module configuration value at runtime without restarting nestjs server

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have looking for a solution which will allow me to change module configuration value via an API call in NestJS at runtime without restarting the server. Please see my code below:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/nest')],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to hit an API (controller route), for example: `http://localhost:3000/api/changeMongoURL` and the configuration value of `MongooseModule.forRoot()` will update/change by the API call during server runtime without restarting the NestJS server.

Comment: have you considered using a dynamic module for this ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

One possible way is by using ConfigModule, for more scalability systems I would prefer using dynamic modules. However, here is an example code based on ConfigModule solution:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    // Load .env file
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    // Use ConfigService to access environment variables
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('MONGO_URI'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then, to change `MONGO_URI` variable using API call, you need to create controller or implement logic on existing endpoint:

```
// config.controller.ts
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Controller('config')
export class ConfigController {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  @Post('mongo-uri')
  changeMongoURI(@Body('uri') uri: string) {
    // Update the MONGO_URI variable
    this.configService.set('MONGO_URI', uri);
    // Return a success message
    return { message: 'MONGO_URI changed successfully' };
  }
}
```

For more clarity, head over to the [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) to learn more techniques using Config Module.

### Solution 2: Custom mongo service

```
// mongodb.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { connect, Connection } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class MongoDBService {
  private connection: Connection;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    const mongoURI = this.configService.get('MONGO_URI');
    const options = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
    this.connection = await connect(mongoURI, options);
  }

  getConnection(): Connection {
    if (!this.connection) {
      throw new Error('MongoDB connection has not been established yet');
    }
    return this.connection;
  }

  async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.connection) {
      await this.connection.disconnect();
      this.connection = null;
    }
  }

  async updateURI(uri: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.disconnect();
    this.configService.set('MONGO_URI', uri);
    await this.connect();
  }
}
```

To use this service,you can inject it in the previous controller that I've post it before:

```
// config.controller.ts

import { Controller, Post, Body, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongoDBService } from './mongodb.service';

@Controller('config')
export class ConfigController {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject(MongoDBService) private mongoDBService: MongoDBService,
  ) {}

  @Post('mongo-uri')
  async changeMongoURI(@Body('uri') uri: string) {
    await this.mongoDBService.updateURI(uri);
    return { message: 'MONGO_URI changed successfully' };
  }
}
```

*notice: note that you need to make sure that your application is not using the `MongooseModule` for establishing the `MongoDB` connection. Instead, you should use the `MongoDBService` to manage the connection to the database.*

Comment: thanks for your reply. But your solution does not solve my problem bro. I want to update the MongooseModule.forRoot value in the fly via API call. You can set new variable but you also have to restart the MongooseModule in this case in order to trigger the change. Thanks anyway

Comment: It is not possible to update the `MongooseModule` configuration at runtime without restarting the module because it is initialized during the application bootstrap process. However, I'll update my answer and add custom service to use it to connect with db / update value without making connection with db in AppModule.

Comment: I added the solution 2 section, it should work now!